# How to make instant coffee concentrate drinkable

Tags: coffee-culture, instant

Me and my friends sometimes make **"instant-coffee shots"**.

they're made in the following way:

1.put a tablespoon instant coffee and half a table spoon sugar in a 8 oz cup.

2.add approximately 30-35 ml of hot water in the cup.

3.stir it around so it becomes liquified.

and we drink them like that.

These are pretty gross and I'm wondering if there is something we can do in terms of ingredients (i.e. types of instant coffee,sugar and milk) to improve theses.

Note:I want to keep the amount of instant coffee and liquids held fixed.

Comment: This question will only really yield heavily opinion-based answers as your solution to it tasting 'less bad' is going to vary depending on who you ask. Generally speaking, instant coffee is just simply subpar in flavour and adding anything to alter the flavour is possible and simply dependent on what flavours work for you.

Comment: Add a glass of milk?

Comment: Try substituting water with milk. You'll keep much the same volume and hopefully reduce the instant coffee flavor.